# Dynamically Link to iTunes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, itunes

I need the ability to link to Artists and their associated Albums in iTunes and was wondering how to do this? Before I built a link, but seems to have broken.

Basically process is this, user comes to my website, see's a list of music artists that is dynamically built, and clicks a "Buy" on artist/album they want.

I've seen the Link Maker (https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/), and that doesn't work as you need the artist ID which I don't have.

What would you recommend I redirect the user to iTunes Store to directly put them on the correct page?

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far?

Comment: So I'm basically dynamically building the URL as such:

http://click.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/stat?id=/V0y3ifvJfM&offerid=78941&type=3&subid=0&tmpid=1826&RD_PARM1=http%253A%252F%252Fphobos.apple.com%252FWebObjects%252FMZSearch.woa%252Fwa%252FadvancedSearchResults%253Fmedia%253Dmusic%2526artistTerm%253D';

then I append the artist and album to the end. This was working until something changed. Not sure what, but trying to do something similar.